# Is there a way to provoke server-side errors from client?

Tags: r, trello, httr

I'm sending GET requests to Trello API, and I need to test my error handling script. Can I send something that will reliably provoke server-side error?

Comment: Do you need to provoke Trello into errors? If not, you can hit https://httpbin.org/ to get back pretty much whatever response you want.

Comment: Interesting. Does it send back actual error messages, or do I have to tell it what to send back? like /status/:code ?

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks! :) I think this would be useful for many people, so feel free to post regular answer for me to accept.

Comment: Okay, maybe not "pretty much whatever response you want", just some useful patterns. But is it okay for you to hit a non-Trello server? Then there should be a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Fine for me, I just needed >= 500 in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is have a server generate HTTP error code replies, and you are fine with not using the real Trello API server (but can switch to another host), you could give [HttpBin](https://httpbin.org/) a try. It's a free, anonymous, hosted service that just replies with whatever status you ask it for.